# nvidia OpenGL extension not available even with a compatible graphics card and updated driver

Tags: opengl, gpu, nvidia, opengl-4

I have a 440 GT Nvidia card.
I need support for opengl 4.3 which contains a new GL_NV_bindless_texture extension that i need to use.

I upgraded my driver and, as it says, OpenGl 4.3 would be available to all Kepler or Fermi based GPUs. Mine is on the list. You can see it here:

[Official update site](https://developer.nvidia.com/opengl-driver)

But no matter what i do, i got no OpenGL 4.3 support. I upgraded, but it still says i´m in opengl 4.2 -> no extension allowed.

How come that be?  Aren´t i able to use this special extension?.

Comment: I´m starting to think that the support is not still available, but they just added all those ARB extensions implemented. But the rest are still being added.. Is that true?

Comment: An extension being added to the driver does not mean it will show up in your system. Your hardware simply can't do bindless textures; you need a Kepler class GPU for this to work (see Nicol Bolas answer). Only with hardware actually supporting the feature the extension becomes available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need support for opengl 4.3 which contains a new GL_NV_bindless_texture extension that i need to use.

This is wrong, and the source of your problem. NV_bindless_texture does not come from OpenGL 4.3. Indeed, the [extension specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/bindless_texture.txt) doesn't even require 4.3; it's written against 4.0 which it requires.

More important for you, NV_bindless_texture [requires Kepler (GeForce GT6xx+) hardware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Kepler#Features). So no driver update is going to make it available to you.

Comment: S**t ! GT6xx+ ???....  that´s awefull... I don´t have that much money for it.

Thanks for the answers. I´m new to internals of extensions and gpus. Learning right now. Knowing what i need when i need to use an extension is new to me. I thought it came with the drivers... obviously , now i underestand. Very nice!

Comment: @darkgaze: The low-end GeForce 6xx's can be had for ~$50. Granted, you get what you pay for in terms of performance.

Comment: I will never pay more than 100 euros (120 dollars) for a graphics card. I bought a super 8800 GTX for 500 dollars some time ago, and it was burned just a year after because they were not tested enough time..... No more. I´ll wait untill i get those for less money. Thanks :)